# Material-UI - understanding 10px simplification

Tags: css, reactjs, themes, material-ui, font-size

I don't get why we need to do this for the 10px simplification:

```
html {
   font-size: 62.5%; /* 62.5% of 16px = 10px */
}
```

It wasn't supposed to the following code do all the work?

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    // Tell Material-UI what's the font-size on the html element is.
    htmlFontSize: 10,
  },
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using [CssBaseline](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/#css-baseline)?

Comment: @RyanCogswell Hi, no.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I've read the documentation on CssBaseline, but still don't get it why the htmlFontSize doesn't have the same effect as the font-size: 62.5%. Even in the theme documentation, I find it pretty hard to understand it.:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `htmlFontSize` property of `typography` in the theme does **not control** the font-size of the `html` element; it just tells Material-UI what size you used on it. Material-UI then uses that size to control how it [converts px units to rem units](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.1/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createTypography.js#L45) when determining the font sizes for all the different typography variants.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the CSS base.

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        html: {
          fontSize: '62.5%'
        }
      }
    }
  }})
```

Answer (score 1):

In v5 it would be something like this:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        html: {
          fontSize: '62.5%',
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```