# MaterialUi set fontSize ratio globally

Tags: css, material-ui, font-size

Based on Material's [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#global-css) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60112664/material-ui-understanding-10px-simplification) I've been trying to set a default font-size on the html tag because my app uses `rem` and the container where it is integrated uses the default 1rem = 16px, so the design is a bit broken.
My theme looks like:

```
typography: {
    htmlFontSize: 10,
    ...
},
overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        html: {
          fontSize: '62.5%',
        },
    ...
```

I'd expect the output css to contain something like `html{font-size:62.5%;}` but it doesn't so of course the style is messed up. Should I target `html` in a different way?

Comment: I think you should just use an css file. MUI styles are only for components

Comment: I don't really have access to the integrating component's code, my goal is to make it work  in any page that doesn't have the desired settings.

Comment: Are you using the `CssBaseline` component? Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Jus create an CSS file and import it

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code, and it works just fine. Double check if you are wrapping your component with `ThemeProvider` passing your `theme` config as `theme` prop and you're using `<CssBaseline />`.

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    htmlFontSize: 10
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      "@global": {
        html: {
          fontSize: "62.5%"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

---

Inspecting the `html` styles, we can see that `font-size: 62.5%;` is set.

[image]

[image: Edit nostalgic-hoover-rm7ht]